# Errors when doing an exception with requests in python

Tags: python, json, exception, python-requests

I've been searching for the reason behind my issue to no avail. It worked before I added the exception handler so I'm relatively perplexed. I am new to python, JSON, APIs, and sql, but not to programming.

```
def getSyllables(word):
conn = sqlite3.connect("wordbase.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT * FROM words WHERE Word =?', [word])
syllables = 0
if (c.fetchone() == None):
    url = 'http://rhymebrain.com/talk?function=getWordInfo&word=' + word
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        j = json.loads(r.text)
        rememberSyllables(word, int(j['syllables'])
        syllables = int(j['syllables'])
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        syllables = 0
else:
    syllables = c.fetchone[1]
return syllables
```

The error I get now is:

```
syllables = int(j['syllables'])
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And if I remove that (Even though I'm fairly certain that the syntax is correct?):

```
except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

`

Comment: You are missing a parenthesis on this line: `rememberSyllables(word, int(j['syllables'])` (add one at the end)

Comment: Thanks, I feel silly now. Three of my pals did't even catch it.

Comment: This appears to be off-topic as it was caused by a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very simple, you haven't closed the previous line's parentheses:

```
rememberSyllables(word, int(j['syllables']))
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: Well, I apologize for wasting everyone's time. Cannot believe I didn't catch that (even had some friends check it out too). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`rememberSyllables(word, int(j['syllables']))` Here the extra ) would solve the issue!!